# relative path or absolute path for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zend-framework, relative-path

I'm sorry for simple question. I need determinate jquery in my project, actually when I used to insert direct link to `<script>`. It works:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

But when I use relative path it doesn't work.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript" >
```

this is my directory:

[image: folder tree]

Comment: Based on the listed paths, your relative path should be `../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js`.

Comment: Your relative path should be from where the HTML file relative is to the JS file. Therefore the path should be: `<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">`

Comment: add ../ to path ../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: from where you are inserting the <script>,is it already written in you main file or you are inserting it dynamically

Comment: What is the URL that displays in your browser when you are viewing the `index.phtml` page? A relative path would have to be relative to that, not relative to the actual files on the file system.

Comment: @JLRishe http://localhost/index/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **main file** and **jquery file** are in **different** **folders**. 
Main file in `scripts/` folder and jquery file in `js/` folder.
Just change path to:

```
../js/jquery-1.11.1.js
```

`../` directory means `scripts/` folder.
So your code will be:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript" >
```

Remember, file names in folders and in your code must be the same.

Hope it'll help :)

Comment: please, make a screenshot of your folder tree or something like that...where is jquery loading? in `list.phtml` file?

Comment: I did that , ps: tnx for comment

Comment: @afn Solved! your jquery has name `jquery-1.11.1.js`, not `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` !

Answer (score 2):

Your `js` folder should be in your `public` folder.

In your layout try this:

```
<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'); ?>
```

Comment: Have you find a solution? And merry Christmas :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a compelling reason to use relative paths, I suggest using an absolute path. It will not break if your page moves to a new location:

```
<script src="/scripts/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" >
```